# Sort 2D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort the numbers in each array from greatest to smallest, but only the first one is being sorted. Do I need another nested loop? I'm stuck.

```
function sortNums(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     arr[i] = arr[i].sort(function(a, b){return b-a;});
     return arr; 
  }
}

sortNums([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the `return` keyword the function immediately terminated. Move it outside the iteration and you should be good:

```
function sortNums(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     arr[i] = arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
       return b - a;
     });
  }
  return arr;
}

sortNums([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: @Austin No problem, sometimes you just stare yourself blind on the problem :-)